# Calculating bipartite graph in networkx

Tags: python, networkx, bipartite

Assume following exemplary edgelist:

```
source,target,weight
162600,117237,200
192084,50240,200
200854,125014,200
166729,37059,5
157279,77297,1
186788,35124,2
199103,112437,5
194523,125618,5
169139,103847,5
156565,85646,5
157159,85646,10
168455,115687,15
139567,108206,5
172702,120323,5
175029,120590,5
167596,85646,10
202163,83381,15
163786,109135,5
183035,124200,4
154266,124200,2
187899,124200,20
190849,124200,8
169657,118867,11
157848,101997,2
143224,87832,1
140758,101009,21
197618,101009,20
175454,50240,4
150071,112472,10
199517,121453,20
```

As you can see, some elements of `source` have a common `target`. Therefore, I thought it would make sense to calculate and visualize a bipartite graph in network X.

The [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/bipartite.html) shows how it's done with manual values but I wonder how it can be applied to the edgelist from above (including weights.

I would be very thankful if someone could provide an example using the data above, though the input data might result in a sparse network.

Comment: Are you asking how to import an edgelist into networkx? Or how to determine if a network is bipartite? Or how to create a visualization? Give a little more information about where you are stuck and the problem you are having.

Comment: I know how to visualize a network. But I don't know how to modify the network/edgelist so that it's bipartite.

Comment: So, a bipartite network is typically a network with two different types of nodes, where edges between nodes of the same type are not possible. For example, we might have a dataset of which people attended each of N parties. We can represent this as a bipartite graph where edges are between a person and the parties they attended. In this example, it's not possible for edges to exist between 2 parties or between 2 people.

It's strange, therefore, to ask about making a graph bipartite - it is typically bipartite based on how it was created.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the theory behind it, I'm just not sure about the code. I know that based on the data above there exist a few bipartite connections. For instance 156565 - 157159

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to run smoothly the add_weighted_edges_from() function in a directed graph. This just after placing your input data in a tuple list, as requested.
Take a look to this [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/tutorial/tutorial.html) for more information

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

INPUT = [
    (162600,117237,200),
    (192084,50240,200),
    (200854,125014,200),
    (166729,37059,5),
    (157279,77297,1),
    (186788,35124,2),
    (199103,112437,5),
    (194523,125618,5),
    (169139,103847,5),
    (156565,85646,5),
    (157159,85646,10),
    (168455,115687,15),
    (139567,108206,5),
    (172702,120323,5),
    (175029,120590,5),
    (167596,85646,10),
    (202163,83381,15),
    (163786,109135,5),
    (183035,124200,4),
    (154266,124200,2),
    (187899,124200,20),
    (190849,124200,8),
    (169657,118867,11),
    (157848,101997,2),
    (143224,87832,1),
    (140758,101009,21),
    (197618,101009,20),
    (175454,50240,4),
    (150071,112472,10),
    (199517,121453,20)
]

G=nx.DiGraph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(INPUT)

elarge = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] > 22]
esmall = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight'] <= 21]

pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=1)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))

# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=700)

# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=elarge,
                       width=6)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=esmall,
                       width=1, alpha=0.5, edge_color='b', style='dashed')

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=12, font_family='sans-serif')

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

This should be the output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hack-ish way I have found to achieve loading bipartite sparse or otherwise network with weights into networkx is first to save said sparse matrix to tab txt (via pandas here) and then load it with `bipartite.read_edgelist` with `data` parameter specifying edge weights

```
INPUT.to_csv('test.edgelist',sep='\t',header=False,index=False)
G = bipartite.read_edgelist(
    'test.edgelist', nodetype=int, data=(("weight", float),)
)
list(G.edges(data=True))
```

Loading the saved edges in this way returns a networkx object. Once the (sparse) bipartite object is loaded, you can query top and bottom nodes:

```
top_nodes = {n for n, d in G.nodes(data=True) if d["bipartite"] == 0}
bottom_nodes = set(G) - top_nodes
```